# "Friendless" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, adjective, derivation

I am looking for a general strategy for translating adjectives like "friendless" into Latin.
My interest is general, but for concreteness I will discuss my thoughts in light of this example.

There appear to be a couple of mechanisms:

- The example *mens > amens* suggests **abamicus*, which does not appear to exist.
- The example *sanguis > exsanguis* suggests **examicus* or **eximicus*, which also don't exist.
- Combining the derivation types *barba > barbatus* and *ornatus > inornatus* suggests **inamicatus* or **inamicatus*, again leading to nothing in a dictionary.
- The Greek privative *a-* appears to be more productive than any Latin counterpart, and [*ἄφιλος*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)%2Ffilos) is a thing.
  Perhaps this could be adapted as **aphilus* in Latin.

Often the need for such an adjective can be avoided by recasting the sentence (e.g. with the relative clause *qui amicos non habet*), but my focus here is on finding suitable adjectives.
I know full well that especially in a scientific context any new adjective can be defined and used, so the question concerns adjectives that are more easily understood and accepted as good Latin.
Another aspect to be mindful of is interference with other derivatives, like *inimicus*, "enemy".

Questions:

1. Am I missing derivations or other approaches in my list above?
2. Is any of the derivations productive enough that I could fairly use it to coin new words?
   Or should I always just produce a list of guesses and see if any exist, and give up if they don't?

Comment: Typically Latin seems to use phrases with, for example, *solutus, vacuus, expers* or *carens*.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Care to write that into an answer? It'd make a useful one, even without expanding.

Comment: As a sort of follow-up to Sebastian Koppehel's suggestion, the phrasing in *In Verrem* actio 2, 4.148 suggests that Cicero would use *nudus ac desertus* for this: ecce autem nova turba atque rixa, ne tamen istum omnino Syracusis sine amicis, sine hospitibus, plane nudum esse ac desertum putetis!

Comment: @cnread Like Spaniards whould use *sin amigos* for this?

Comment: I think that *inemicus* may work

Comment: @Dolphínus If you can argue why (is it attested, is there a good analogy to support it, is there a risk if confusion, and so on), that'd make an answer. My first reaction is that I would badly misinterpret that word if it came without explanation.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta my analogy is inermis, everything else I have no idea. Which actually makes my suggestion in inemicis

Comment: @Dolphínus See the discussion about *inimicus* in the question. The risk of confusion is pretty bad. But the example of *inermis* would make a good addition to the list of prefixes.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta So do yo think that Spaniards shoud not have both the words *Invisible* and *Invencible*? they get confounded a lot by children.